# Need to reduce the number of views

Tags: android, gridview, view

I need to create more than 80 numbers total in my layout. Currently I'm getting a "**has more than 80 views, bad for performance**" message and I would like to find an alternative way to do this. I have looked into GridView but I couldn't seem to find a way to apply the background to each number like the picture in the links below (I can't upload pic yet).

[image: 80 buttons]

[image: RelativeLayout Outline]

### .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_play"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_play"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:baselineAligned="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@id/linearlayout_button" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
        android:orientation="vertical">   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_favorite_numbers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="@string/favorite_numbers"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_numbers1to10"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"            
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number1"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_1"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number2"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_2"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number3"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_3"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number4"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_4"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_5"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number6"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_6"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number7"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_7"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number8"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_8"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number9"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_9"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />              

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number10"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_10"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- 11 to 20 -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_numbers11to20"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number11"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_11"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number12"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_12"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number13"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_13"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number14"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_14"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number15"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_15"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number16"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_16"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number17"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_17"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number18"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_18"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number19"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_19"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number20"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_20"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- 21 to 30 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_numbers21to30"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number21"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_21"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number22"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_22"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number23"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_23"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number24"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_24"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number25"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_25"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number26"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_26"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number27"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_27"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number28"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_28"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number29"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_29"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number30"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_30"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- 31 to 40 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_numbers31to39"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number31"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_31"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number32"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_32"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number33"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_33"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number34"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_34"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number35"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_35"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number36"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_36"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number37"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_37"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number38"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_38"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number39"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_39"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number40"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_40"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />                      

        </LinearLayout>         
         <!-- 41 to 47 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout_numbers41to47"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number41"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_41"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number42"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_42"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number43"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_43"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number44"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_44"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number45"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_45"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number46"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_46"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number47"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/number_47"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/number_background"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />  

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number48"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number49"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/textView_number50"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="45dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
        ... 

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: see gridview adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using GridView!

Below is my code:

### Fragment1.java:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public Fragment1() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_numbers);
    gridView.setAdapter(new TextViewAdapter(getActivity()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

### TextViewAdapter.java:

```
public class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public TextViewAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView textView;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(65, 85));
        textView.setTextSize(18.0f);
        textView.setGravity(0x11);
    } 
    else
    {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    textView.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    textView.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));

    return textView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.number_deselect, R.drawable.number_deselect, R.drawable.number_deselect, 
    R.drawable.number_deselect, R.drawable.number_deselect, R.drawable.number_deselect,
    R.drawable.number_deselect, R.drawable.number_deselect, R.drawable.number_deselect
};
```

}

### fragment_1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview_numbers"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="33dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center" />
```